# thingsboard - getting ip of telemetry sender

Tags: thingsboard

I'm trying to find the ip address of the person who sent telemetry to a particular device. Is there a way to get it out? I was thinking of trying through the rull-chain because the data goes through it but I'm not sure how

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to get this done via Rulechain. But you could add the IP of the sender to the device payload before sending to ThingsBoard (e.g. attribute with ip information).